# MacOS 11.4 Perl: dyld: missing lazy symbol called

Tags: macos, perl, macos-big-sur, catalyst

I get the following error when I'm running a perl catalyst application locally on mac big sur 11.4:

```
dyld: missing lazy symbol called
```

the application is compiling correctly, but when I enter the url in the browser I get this error and the site can't be reached.

my @INC from `perl -V` looks like following:

```
  @INC:
    /Users/user-1/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/user-1/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.2
    /Users/user-1/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/user-1/perl5/lib/perl5
    /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.30
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.30
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.2
    /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.30
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30
```

I don't know if it's related to catalyst or maybe xcode (I have version 12.5).

Comment: Can you try to reduce the application down to a minimum that still produces the error? Then share that code here (update your question). This will make it easier for us to try reproduce the error. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: I think it might be related to DBD::mysql.

I installed it via `cpanm --configure-args="--libs='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/lib' --cflags='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/include/mysql'" DBD::mysql --force`.

Maybe that is wrong. Probably a problem with openssl?

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18700) issue..

Comment: it seems to be some linking issue with ssl and crypto, unfortunately the fix at your link doesn't help